# Site getting redirect to www.www.sitename.com

Tags: asp.net, web-config, redirect

I am having this problem with my site getting redirect to www.www.sitename.com.

I have this code written in web.config which working fine for my other website.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>

        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

This is 100% wokring code other sites but having problem of www.www.sitename.com on this site **srilanka-tours.co**

Comment: [URLRewrite](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-rewrite-protocol-http-https-in-the-action)

Comment: BTW, I just visited your srilanka-tours.co website and got _not_ redirected to a double-www URL. Maybe some caching issue in your browser after playing around with rewrites?

Comment: I have updated the code you send me and it is working fine. but still confuse why it is not working with the general code.

Comment: @MaazAli If you have time to spend, you can [use IIS Failed Request Tracing to "debug" your rewrite rules](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules).

Comment: thanks @UweKeim, I will look into this article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing it less generic and more focused on your actual host name?

E.g.:

```
<rule name="Redirect to WWW">
    <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.srilanka-tours\.co$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" 
                url="http://www.srilanka-tours.co/{R:1}" 
                redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

(This is an excerpt from a real-world rewrite rule).

The above rule is similar to what you get when using the "Canonical Domain Name" in the IIS Managers' "wizard" for creating rewrite rules. [See the article on Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension).

Comment: What is difference between (R:1) and (R:0)? you used (R:1) in you code

Comment: THanks for your help. Site working fine after i have updated the tour.